# Group multiple requests using Vuex

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, vuex

Currently we have Vue + Vuex application which uses a lot of custom components per page. We use MongoDB as database.

Each component loads some data on initialization from API endpoint:

```
async loadData() {
  const data = await getData('/api/some_url', {path_in_db: 'some.path.to.db')
}
```

Now we met a problem when there are more than 50 requests going to backend server during page initialization.

**What I've tried to do:**

Created Vuex store

```
import { INITIAL_DATA_GET, INITIAL_DATA_SET, INITIAL_DATA_CLEAR } from './actions';

const getDefaultState = () => {
  return {};
};

const mutations = {
  [INITIAL_DATA_SET]: (mutationState, obj) => {
    const { request = {} } = mutationState;
    if (!request[obj.ref]) {
      request[obj.ref] = { paths: [] };
    }
    request[obj.ref].paths.push(obj.resPath);
    Vue.set(mutationState, 'request', request);
  },
  [INITIAL_DATA_CLEAR]: (mutationState) => {
    Vue.set(mutationState, getDefaultState());
  },
};

const actions = {
  [INITIAL_DATA_SET]: ({ commit }, obj) => {
    commit(INITIAL_DATA_SET, obj);
  },
  [INITIAL_DATA_CLEAR]: ({ commit }) => {
    commit(INITIAL_DATA_CLEAR);
  },
};

const getters = {
  [INITIAL_DATA_GET]: getterState => getterState,
};
```

From each component I run

```
store.dispatch(INITIAL_DATA_SET, {
  ref: this.ref,
  resPath: this.resPath,
});
```

After all components being initialized, last `console.log(mutationState)` looks like this

```
getters: {
  request: {
    5d879e7af0a317002e5b4759: {
       paths: ['path.to.a', 'path.to.b', 'path.to.c'...]
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there any way how to wait all components to be loaded, and only then send one request to database?
- What is the best practice to implement things like this (fetch multiple requests)?
- What is the best scenario: send one big request or multiple small ones?

Answer (score 1):

When waiting for multiple child components to be fully loaded after handling asynchronous operations, you will likely want to use `$emit` to set a flag that the component is ready. Once your parent detects all children are ready, you can trigger whatever you'd like then. This is commonly used when working with skeleton components and spinners.

Making multiple asynchronous requests can be done different ways depending on your needs. If you just want quick and easy handling, group them all up in a `Promise.all` array and do it in one go. If the order matters, then you can batch them together in Promises as you need.

There isn't really a "best" scenario. If you have the bandwith and use good UI/UX practices, you can send them singularly or batched. If your top components component take less time, have those called first and then lower components so the user gets to be interactive quicker. There are numerous ways to do this.

But if you're making 50 calls to the back-end server just on initialization, is your server set up properly? Are the endpoints efficient? There is only so much you can do from the front.

Comment: I know about `$emit`, but this is really not good fit for out needs.
Our real problem is we have for example page with multiple sections, each section could have multiple components. All those sections and components are dynamic, so we don't know exactly which information from database we need.

Ex.: let's imagine our database structure looks like `level1: {level2: {level3:{}}} etc` Currently to handle multiple requests we just load `level1` and then through `props` passing this big JSON object to children. But I guess this is not good in terms of `level1` could be very big...

Comment: I was thinking about using `Promise.all`. But how do you think this could be implemented using Vuex? This still would be multiple requests? If so, this is not our solution, because of implementation on `mounted` event looks better, and could be isolated better in terms of component.

Comment: If you have a massive JSON going in at the first level and passing down multiple levels, sounds like you'd be much better off using Vuex and keeping the data in the store to be accessed by whatever component.

Comment: Promise.all works the same way in the store. You can put asynchronous functions in actions and then commit. You can even do the asynchronous fetches in the component on mount or whenever and just store it in the state after you get data.